# send form with parent().serialize()

Tags: jquery, ajax

i´ve a form which sends the result via ajax. Sending with the "submit button" is not the problem, but when I change the "select" field, no data is submited. It should be a "parent" problem, some divs and spans are around of the input field. 
Thanks for help

```
            <form>

            // calls the script by changing but no data is submited - there are some divs and spans around the "select" 
            <div id="e.g.">
                <div>
                    <select id="version" size="1" name="version" class="change"><option value="1" selected>XXX</option><option value="2">YYY</option></select>
                </div>
            </div>

            //calls the script by clicking and all datas are submited
            <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Generate preview and HTML code">

            </form>

            <script>
            $(function(){
              function send() {

                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "script.pl",
                  data: $(this).parent().serialize(), 
                  success: function(msg) {
                    $('#xyz').html(msg); 
                  }
                });
                return false;
              }
              //send with the submit button
                $("#submit_button").click(send);
              //send when the select field is changed
                $('.change').change(send);

            });  
            </script>
```

Comment: Give an id to form element and then use serialize method to send data like $('#formid').serialize()

Answer (score 0):

find the solution by myself

```
data: $('#id_of_the_form').serialize(),
```